# Is there a way to better manage my data usage in my COBOL program

Tags: memory, cobol

I am currently writing a program that finds the greatest prime factor or a number in COBOL. Here is what I have:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. EULER2.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01 num1 PIC 9(12) VALUE 600851475143.
    01 num2 PIC 9(6) VALUE 2.
    01 smallest PIC 9(6) VALUE 0. 
    01 num3 PIC 9(6). 
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
MAIN-PROCEDURE. 

PERFORM whileLoop UNTIL num1 <= num2.
DISPLAY "Greatest prime of large number " smallest. 
STOP RUN.

whileLoop.
    IF FUNCTION MOD(num1, num2) = 0
        DIVIDE num2 INTO num1.
        IF(smallest LESS THAN num2)
            SET smallest TO num2
            ADD 1 TO smallest
    ELSE
        ADD 1 TO num2
    END-IF.
```

This code works. But in order to get the correct answer, I have to add the 1 to smallest since it will return the largest prime number less than 1. Also when I check things like smallest, there is a lot more output than if I were to run this program in another language. I was wondering if there was a memory issue I have here or if I could get insight to how COBOL is running this.

Answer (score 5):

There is no memory usage issue. The run time is affected by the use of display values rather than binary values (I used `comp-5`) and that all even numbers are tested despite these not being possible primes.

As originally written, the loop was terminating when `num1 <= num2`. After adding `1` to `num2`, `num2` became equal to `num1`, but `smallest` had a value that was one less than `num1`. By changing the loop termination to `num1 < num2`, the final value was saved in `smallest`. This removed the need to add the final `1`.

In the code, I added statements to display `num2`. The numbers displayed are the prime factors than comprise the original number. I also replaced all separator periods, after statements, to a separate line at the end of their paragraphs.

I changes to address a comment and for other concerns.

If `num1` is prime or has a factor, where either gives a result of more than 6 digits, there will be an overflow of `num2` that will result in a "divide by zero" exception. That is to say that the `PICTURE` clause for `num2` should never be smaller than that for `num1`. I made the `PICTURE` clauses 18 digits, which, in most cases, will be 64-bits.

I added some display formatting to make it "neater".

I changed the `SET` statement to a `MOVE` statement. Be aware that using a `SET` statement for assignment between two numeric data items is a syntax error in both the 1985 and 2002 standards.

> ISO/IEC 1989:2002
>   SET statement
>   14.8.35.2 Syntax rules
>   4) If identifier-1 references a numeric data item, index-name-2 shall be specified.

Additional changes address speed. `num2` is checked for `2`, then for the odd numbers `3` and above. The search for the next factor is terminated when `num2` is greater than the square root of `num1`. The largest 18-digit prime, `999,999,999,999,999,991`, may still take several minutes, but is about a billion times faster than without these changes.

Code:

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. EULER2.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 num1 comp-5 PIC S9(18) VALUE 600851475143.
   01 num2 comp-5 PIC S9(18) VALUE 2.
   01 smallest comp-5 PIC S9(18) VALUE 1.
   01 temp comp-5 PIC S9(18).
   01 rem comp-5 PIC S9(18).
   01 sqrt-num1 comp-5 PIC S9(18).
   01 num-display PIC BZZZ,ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZ9.
   01 trimmed-display PIC X(23).
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAIN-PROCEDURE. 
       PERFORM get-sqrt-num1
       DISPLAY "Factors:"
       PERFORM whileLoop UNTIL num1 < num2
       MOVE smallest TO num-display
       PERFORM trim-num
       DISPLAY SPACE
       DISPLAY "Greatest prime of large number: "
           trimmed-display
       STOP RUN
       .

   whileLoop.
       DIVIDE num2 INTO num1 GIVING temp REMAINDER rem
       IF rem = 0
           MOVE temp TO num1
           PERFORM get-sqrt-num1
           IF(smallest LESS THAN num2)
               MOVE num2 TO smallest
           end-if
           MOVE num2 TO num-display
           PERFORM trim-num
           DISPLAY trimmed-display
       ELSE
           IF num2 > 2
               ADD 2 TO num2
           ELSE
               ADD 1 TO num2
           END-IF
           IF num2 > sqrt-num1
               MOVE num1 TO num2
           END-IF
       END-IF
       .

   get-sqrt-num1.
       COMPUTE sqrt-num1 = FUNCTION SQRT (num1)
       .

   trim-num.
       UNSTRING num-display DELIMITED ALL SPACE
           INTO trimmed-display (1:1) trimmed-display
       .
```

Output:

```
Factors:
71
839
1,471
6,857

Greatest prime of large number: 6,857
```

Comment: While this may need a much more huge number to have an effect - there would be a doubled DIVIDE` in case of a match.
Has it a better performance with using `DIVIDE .. REMAINDER` i your environment?

What about the common "add a sign so the runtime has not to check if it needs to remove it" suggestion?

Note: Not all environments will `DISPLAY` a packed field as unpacked (possible portability issue).

Comment: Thank you for this good and detailed answer (and I'd still suggest to replace the non-standard `SET`, if I remember correctly only ACUCOBOL-GT and OpenCOBOL will allow these without any warning).

Comment: @SimonSobisch - My Micro Focus compiler did not report an error, but I did not turn on conformance checking.